# Wire to wire connector for multiple DC outputs from single input

Tags: dc, connector, wire

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a connector that I could use to distribute a single 5v line into many devices such as the picture below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feuGAe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm sure that there would be something similar that is used in computers for this purpose but I am basically trying to avoid creating a PCB or having a connector with multiple wires coming out of a single pin.

To clarify: I'm looking for a relatively small wire to wire connector.

Comment: A USB hub maybe? Not sure how much current they would be rated for.

Comment: Unfortunately a USB hub wouldn't be appropriate for my application here. I'm looking more for something similar to a Molex or JST connector.

Comment: Creating a PCB is your best option here even though you don't want to do that.  I could not see a feasible option with a single wire.  You will need to distribute your voltage through a plane of some sort.  Audio cables sometime have splitter to connect multiple speakers together for example.

Comment: *"I am trying to avoid having a connector with multiple wires coming out of a single pin"* Why? This is actually the best solution, here. Just as they do in PCs, as you mentioned. You could daisy-chain them, this way, you have at most two wires coming out, which allows for smaller pins (and therefore smaller connectors).

Comment: I think that daisy chaining may be the best option. I really did think that there might be a connector out there for this purpose though... maybe I'll invent one.

Comment: Would a bus bar work? Or are they too big for your application?

Comment: What are the currents?

Answer (score 2):

You could use barrier terminal strips.  There are jumper things that will bridge two or more terminals to give any reaonalbe number of bussed terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean such a [thing](http://www.wago.us/products/terminal-blocks-and-connectors/installation-connectors/compact-splicing-connectors-for-all-conductor-types-222-series/overview/index.jsp)? They work for both AC and DC.

[image: photo]

Comment: These Wago terminals are great, I use them at work all the time but I'm looking for something a little more like a proper connector with crimp terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Are you envisaging some sort of in-line 'T' join/splice in a cable? This is a messy look and won't be great for current carrying capacity though.

Quite cheap on Ebay. Packs of 50 are only a few dollars.

What was your application? How long would the runs be?

[image]